# existence and uniqueness of Initial value problem

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

We just read Picard existence and uniqueness theorem for initial value problems. Please someone give us one example to show that IVP may not have a solution, and second example to show that if solution exists then it may not be unique

Comment: Are you more than one :D

Comment: Hint: Picard (basically) works when the $F$ is Lipschitz (in $y'=F(x,y)$) - play around with some standard non-Lipschitz $F$ and see what happens.

Comment: dear Jaideep by "we" I mean all my classmates

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/757245/when-does-initial-value-problems-have-no-solutions-more-than-one-solution-pre

Answer (score 1):

**No solution:**
$$
\dot x =\begin{cases}-1&x\ge 0\\1&x<0\end{cases}
$$
with $x(0)=0$. In some weakened generalized context, $x\equiv0$ could be called a solution, but since $\dot x=0$ it does not satisfy this ODE in the strong sense.

Note that the Peano theorem guarantees local solutions if the right side is continuous, which covers all the "nice" cases.

**More than one solution:** The classical example is 
$$
\dot x=2\sqrt{|x|}
$$
with $x(0)=0$ which has solutions 
$$
x(t)=\begin{cases}0&0\le t<c\\\pm(t-c)^2&t\ge c\end{cases}
$$
for any $c>0$ including $c=\infty$.